# Facebook SDK error 'Required "app_id" key not supplied in config

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I have implemented login system that return **access token** on my application end using facbook graph api. But while I tried to user information using following scripts I am getting error.

My scripts:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'appId'  => 'appid',
'secret' => 'secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
    ]);
try {
 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
 $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', 'some access token');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

 $user = $response->getGraphUser();

 echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
```

Error experienced:

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Required "app_id" key     not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable   "FACEBOOK_APP_ID"' in B:\xampp\htdocs\SocialAPI\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-   dev\src\Facebook\Facebook.php:133 Stack trace: #0    B:\xampp\htdocs\SocialAPI\loginSuccess.php(22): Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in B:\xampp\htdocs\SocialAPI\facebook-php-  sdk-v4-5.0-dev\src\Facebook\Facebook.php on line 133
```

Please let me know i can I resolve this error.

Comment: Maybe `appId` and `app_id` are different somehow?

Comment: You need to create an app on the facebook portal before you can use the sdk. There you will get the appid and secret key to make requests successfully. Then you add the keys to your code... visit developers.facebook.co. For more info

Comment: Have u creared the app in facebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's seems that your Facbook.php file expecting **app_id** instead of **appId**

In order to resolve at first open your following file:

```
B:\xampp\htdocs\SocialAPI\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-   dev\src\Facebook\Facebook.php
```

Then look for **appId** whether exist or not. If not **appId** not found then update your config as following:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id'  => 'appid',
'secret' => 'secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2'
]);
```

If your issue doesn't resolve please let know.